# Bug in alert message and button after axios request

Tags: react-native

So i have this piece of code,im trying to find out if a book is rented .

Im doing an axios request and seems to workfine .Actualy all of it is working fine ,my problem is that when the book is rented and payed when i press to show it in my home page first it shows the alert and then it enters the book.Also i need to double click to enter the book,seems that it stuck after axios request somehow because it displaying the axios setBookIsRent and when i click again then it enters with the alert displaying.

Anyone know where seems to be the bug here?

```
function rentChecker(){
    try{
      //Checking if the book is Rented
      axios.post('http://***********/getBooksRent',
      {
        userID : global.id,
        bookID : bookShow.id
      }).then((response) => { 
          const data = response.data;
          console.log(data[0])
          setBookIsRent(data);
      })

    
      var today = new Date().getTime()/1000;
      console.log(today);
        
      var bookRentTimeStamp = new Date(bookIsRent[0].TimeEnd).getTime()/1000;
      console.log(bookRentTimeStamp);

      var checker = (today > bookRentTimeStamp)
      console.log("Real time is greater than rent time ? Answer--> " + checker)

    
      if(bookIsRent[0].bookRented == 1 && (today < bookRentTimeStamp)){ 
        navigation.navigate('WebViewPdf',{paramKey:bookShow}) 
      }
      else if(checker){
        Alert.alert("Forbitten,book not Rented!")
      }
    }catch(error){
      Alert.alert("Forbitten,book not Rented!")
    }
  
  }
```

```
 <Pressable style = {styles.pressableInsideModal} onPress = {() => { rentChecker() }}>
   <Text style = {styles.textInsideModal}>Show Book Rented</Text>
</Pressable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im posting the answer with the help of kirill Novikov so other can find a solution too.

```
//Function to get books Rented and display them 
  function rentChecker(){

      //Checking if the book is Rented
      axios.post('http://******/getBooksRent',
      {
        userID : global.id,
        bookID : bookShow.id
      }).then((response) => { 
          const data = response.data;
          console.log(data[0])
        
      

    
      var today = new Date().getTime()/1000;
      console.log(today);
        
      var bookRentTimeStamp = new Date(data[0].TimeEnd).getTime()/1000;
      console.log(bookRentTimeStamp);

      var checker = (today > bookRentTimeStamp)
      console.log("Real time is greater than rent time ? Answer--> " + checker)

    
      if(data[0].bookRented == 1 && (today < bookRentTimeStamp)){ 
        navigation.navigate('WebViewPdf',{paramKey:bookShow}) 
      }
      else if(checker){
        Alert.alert("Forbitten,book not Rented!")
      }

    }).catch((error) =>{
      Alert.alert("Forbitten,book not Rented!")
    })
  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in wrong error handling. Try to do it with:

```js
function rentChecker() {
  axios.post('http://***********/getBooksRent',
      {
        userID : global.id,
        bookID : bookShow.id
      }).then((response) => { 
          const data = response.data;
          console.log(data[0])
          setBookIsRent(data);
          // Do all work here 
          var today = new Date().getTime()/1000;
          console.log(today);
            
          var bookRentTimeStamp = new Date(bookIsRent[0].TimeEnd).getTime()/1000;
          console.log(bookRentTimeStamp);

          var checker = (today > bookRentTimeStamp)
          console.log("Real time is greater than rent time ? Answer--> " + checker)

        
          if(bookIsRent[0].bookRented == 1 && (today < bookRentTimeStamp)){ 
            navigation.navigate('WebViewPdf',{paramKey:bookShow}) 
          }
          else if(checker){
            Alert.alert("Forbitten,book not Rented!")
          }
      }).catch(error => {
        Alert.alert("Forbitten,book not Rented!")
      })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response,it helped .Its not 100% correct  the problem seems to be the useState ,it was like it needed to render it twice so i place the data[0] where ever i had bookIsRent.Im answer it so other can find the solution too .Again thank you it helped a lot! :)